# Ownership of some qcow files in /var/lib/libvirt/images keeps reverting to root:root

Tags: permissions, 20.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've got five VMs built, but issues with two.  The .qcow files revert to root:root ownership after every reboot, and when they're owned that way, the VMs don't autostart properly.  I can chown them to libvert-qemu:kvm as much as I want, but something keeps changing the ownership.  The other three VMs have no issues.  The two that keep changing permissions were created in Virtual Machine Manager, the other three with virt-install, accessed via serial console.

Ubuntu 20.04, upgraded from 19.

Comment: virt-install and virt-manager use the same code, so it must be details in the config that makes them different. And autostart also should not be affected if running as qemu://system which is the default. But at least for the file ownership I can tell you that it is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/691590 which is an issue since forever and about to be resolved in 20.04.

Comment: Yup, the workaround there addressed the issue.

Comment: The fix is released, no workaround needed anymore in >=20.04